# Random error when capturing a photo on iOS

Tags: ios, swift, avcapturesession, avcapture

I am trying here to capture an image :

```
var stillImageOutput = AVCaptureStillImageOutput()
stillImageOutput!.outputSettings = [AVVideoCodecKey: AVVideoCodecJPEG]

[...] 

if let videoConnection = stillImageOutput.connectionWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo) {
     videoConnection.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation.Portrait
     println("enabled = \(videoConnection.enabled)") //enabled = true
     println("active = \(videoConnection.active)") //active = true
     stillImageOutput.captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection(videoConnection, completionHandler: {
          (sampleBuffer, error) in
          if error != nil {
               println(error)
          }
     })
}
```

**It works perfectly most of the time !**

But sometimes I get an error when calling `captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection` :

```
Error Domain=AVFoundationErrorDomain Code=-11800 "The operation couldn't be completed." 
UserInfo=0x14682110 {NSLocalizedDescription=The operation couldn't be completed., 
NSUnderlyingError=0x1676be30 "The operation couldn't be completed.
(OSStatus error -16400.)", 
NSLocalizedFailureReason=An unknown error has occured (-16400)}
```

I just want to anticipate that this error will occur. I tried with testing `videoConnection.enabled` and `videoConnection.active` but both seem independant from the error...

What do I need to check to make sure everything is OK before capturing the photo ?

Comment: After much debugging too. I solved my problem with this response : http://stackoverflow.com/a/42691502/7084347

Answer (score 6):

I also got the same error message that you did. After much debugging, I realized that I was inadvertently stopping the capture session before I took my photo. Double check that the `.running` property of your `AVCaptureSession` is `true`.